# Formatting form data using JQuery for AJAX POST and access easily in Laravel (or PHP)?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I need to send form data over AJAX so I can access it easily in Laravel (or using standard PHP methods). It's actually a form using Stripe Checkout that I'm stopping from being auto submitted so I can send over AJAX. Currently I have the code below but suspect variable "formdata" is not formatted correctly before being referenced in $.ajax.

1. What do I need to do to it to make it formatted correctly?
2. Ideally I want to access the separate form elements on the backend as regular POST vars (or actually I'm using Laravel, so via Request->input() method), will this do that?

Thanks

```
$('#booking-form').get(0).submit = function() {
    var formdata = $(this).serializeArray();

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'book',
    data: { formdata },
    success: function (data)
        {
        // Form submitted and processed correctly, success returned
        },
    error: function (data)
        {
        // console.log('Error:', data.responseText);
        }
    });
```

Backend (Laravel 5.4, but I could use raw PHP if I had to):

```
public function book(Request $request)
    {
    $formfield1 = $request->input('formfield1');
    $formfield2 = $request->input('formfield2');
    [etc.]

    }
```

Comment: I don't think you need to send it in an object, try `data: formdata,` instead

Comment: Can you show your html form code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#booking-form').submit( function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'book',
            data: $('#booking-form').serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                // Form submitted and processed correctly, success returned
            },
            error: function (data) {
                // console.log('Error:', data.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Not really familiar with Laravel, but certainly accessing the form fields via native PHP (i.e. `$_POST['formfield1']`) should work perfectly.